# List folders and subfolders from a directory in Excel with hyperlinks?

Tags: excel, list, directory, hyperlink

I am looking for a vb script that would list the folders and subfolders from a directory, and output it to excel so that i could open the folders via hyperlinks.

I am trying to create a sort of directory index that collates about 100 parent folders from  2 directories located on 2 different servers.  Some parent folders have up to 20 subfolders and then a further 5 folders in each subfolder.

Ideally the layout would be like this.

```
Parent Folder              Subdirectory

Folder1                   Sub1          Folder
                                        Folder

                          Sub2          Folder
                                        Folder

                          Sub3          Folder
                                        Folder

Folder2                   Sub1          Folder
```

etc etc.

I have no knowledge of visual basic programming, so if anyone could help you would save me a great deal of time from creating this index manually.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [HOW TO: Recursively Search Directories by Using FileSystemObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601)